# Haskell pattern matching match Map.empty any with any Map.Map k v

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am writing a function which has different operations depending on `Map.Map` in argument if Map is empty or not

Here is my code:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map

testF :: (Ord a, Num a) => Map.Map a a -> [a] -> [a]
testF empty _  = [1024]
testF _ []     = []
testF m (x:xs) = [x] ++ (testF m xs)

main = do
  let a = Map.fromList [(1,2), (3,4)]
  print $ testF Map.empty [1,2,3] -- show [1024]
  print $ testF a [1,2,3] -- show [1024] too
  print $ a == Map.empty -- False
```

Of course GHC already give me notification that lastest line of function is redundant.

```
Pattern match is redundant
   In an equation for ‘testF’: testF m (x : xs) =
```

1. Why every Map.Map can match Map.empty?
2. What should I do to implement my requirement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not matching against `Map.empty`, you're matching against `empty`, which is just a local variable bound to whatever map is coming in. You can't match against `Map.empty` because it's not a constructor.

What you can do instead is:

```
testF m _ | Map.null m = [1024]
```

I.e. use a guard to check whether `m` is empty.

Comment: I saw `Map.Map` source code given a `Tip` and `Bin` constructor for `Map k v` which `empty = Tip`. According to this wiki: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching , pattern matching could match constructor in `data Foo`. So, the problem is Data.Map.Lazy does not export Tip and Bin, right?

Comment: @ccQpein Right. `Map` is abstract (the implementation is private), so you can't directly access its constructors.

Comment: Can also use `ViewPatterns` here, `testF (Map.null -> True) _ = [1024]`, although stylistically I prefer a guard for such a simple case.

Comment: It would also be possible to write a pattern synonym for the empty map, but as @JonPurdy says about the view pattern, it hardly seems worth the trouble. There aren't really any other patterns that would go along with it to form a particularly useful set. I mean, you *could* write patterns for inspecting the first and last elements of the map, but that's just not a common enough operation to worry about.